# How to implement release function in soundpool?

Tags: android, soundpool

hy,,im newbie for android,i have error 
`AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12` when running my application. i read for use `release()` method for fix it, but i don't know how to implement on my code, please help me ?? this is my code,please fix it :)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.talempong);

    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID = spool.load(this, R.raw.doo, 1);

   ImageButton Button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound();



        }

    });
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    spool2 = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundID2 = spool2.load(this, R.raw.re, 1);

    ImageButton Button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
    Button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sound2();
        }
});
```

Comment: can you show us the `logcat` errors?

Comment: this is :) :  "AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12" and "Error creating AudioTrack" please help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Is your sound greater that 1MB? SoudPool doesn't plays sounds that are greater that that.

If it isn't you can use the release after playing the sound.

```
// your code:

this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundID = spool.load(this, R.raw.doo, 1);


//after this you have to: 

spool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener(){

@Override 
    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sound,int sampleId,int status){
        spool.play(teste, 20,20, 1, 0, 1);
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
@Override                       
     public void run(){
         try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
                spool.release();
         } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
         }
        }).start();
    }
});

// in the Thread.sleep put the value in millisecs of the time of your music this is a sample os 2 seconds
```

Comment: i try this but i found error for : The method setOnLoadCompleteListener(SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener) in the type SoundPool is not applicable for the arguments (new OnLoadCompleteListener(){})?? my resource only 7Kb but i have 16 sound  to run with soundpool:)

Comment: Right click the project, goto Properties->Java Compiler->Check the Enable project specific settings->then select the highest compiler compliance level.

If this doesn't work, then right click the project, AndroidTools->Fix project properties.

Comment: don't forget to change the value: 2000 to a value that is greater that your sound duration (in milliseconds)

Comment: `@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.talempong);

        this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        spool = new SoundPool(10, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundID = spool.load(this, R.raw.doo, 1);
    //new for release 
        

       ImageButton Button = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
                Sound();`

Comment: and ` public void Sound(){
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float volume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        spool.play(soundID, volume, volume, 1, 0, 1f);`this is my full sample code,, i dont know to implement your code,, i get some error,, but thanks you very much :)