# When trying to add sound using soundpool gives error AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12

Tags: android

I am using soundpool or playing small size of sound but after sometime sound gets off i am getting error of AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12
What is mean by this line .
Anyone aware about this?

```
  soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sampleId, int status) {
                        soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
                    }
                });
                soundPool.load(GameActivity.this, R.raw.btn_click, 1);
```

Where i should add it.

Comment: You need to release the soundpool.
soundPool.release();
soundPool = null; Then you can use it again.

Comment: Where i should add it? AFter play?

Comment: I am sharing my code.

Answer (score 0):

Release the soundpool before use it again.

```
if(soundPool != null)
{
   soundPool.release(); 
   // soundPool = null;
}
soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sampleId, int status) {
            soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f);
        }
    });
soundPool.load(GameActivity.this, R.raw.hit_black_balloon, 1);
```

Comment: Where i should add it? AFter play?

Comment: When you raise this kind of exception. When you close the screen or try to play it again?

Comment: Try to play it again

Comment: Okey so when you stop the sound write this code and after that again load the new soundpool this will resolve your problem.

Comment: I am not stopping sound , actually i am developing game so when i shoot arrow and when it touches any object then sound  play. I am just calling soundpool.play

Comment: Can you please add some more code so I get some idea. Are you using the code even after close the screen or something like that.

Comment: Try to add this code before soundPool = new SoundPool() and then try.

Comment: i am trying your code.

Comment: For your reference you can [refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21027908/5860777) may be this help you out

Comment: It is not working in my case

Comment: Please add some more code bro.

Comment: if (soundPool != null){
 soundPool = new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);       soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool sp, int sampleId, int status) {  soundPool.play(sampleId, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0, 0, 1.0f)  soundPool.release();  }});soundPool.load(GameActivity.this, R.raw.hit_black_balloon, 1); }

Comment: Please tell me you are cal this soundPool = new SoundPool() everytime?

Comment: yes i am calling this every time

Comment: Which permission? Is this  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"></uses-permission>

Comment: See my updated answer hope this solve your problem.

Comment: Yes this permission.

Comment: Yes i already given this permission

Comment: See my updated post and try that one.

Comment: it is working, now i am testing about my issue.

Comment: Okey :)  if you found the post is helpful please accept the answer so other can see as a helpful answer.

Comment: It solved my problem. Thank you. But i face some other issue.

Comment: Sound gets cut off.

Comment: What you means by Sounds gets cut off?